# How can I implement the current algorithm into a for loop in increments?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, input, console-application

I need the loop to follow the algorithm of the code below. Every loop should take the first day (2) and add the average (.3) to it.

```
startOrganism = 2
startOrganism = int(input("Starting number of organisms:"))

dailyInc = .3
dailyInc = float(input("Average daily increase (percent): "))

numberDaysMulti = 10
numberDaysMulti = int(input("Number of days to multiply: "))

for x in range(numberDaysMulti):

(Needs to be below)

Day 1  2
Day 2  2.6
Day 3  3.38 
etc.
```

Comment: What you show is come code with a `for` loop. Was there a particular algorithm you have in mind? Please update your question with sample input and outputs.

Comment: @quamrana Hey thanks for respoding, I updated my question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've assumed that the user will input the percent daily increase as `0.3` as opposed to `30`:

```py
startOrganism = int(input("Starting number of organisms:"))

dailyInc = float(input("Average daily increase (percent): "))

numberDaysMulti = int(input("Number of days to multiply: "))

percDailyInc = 1 + dailyInc

for day in range(numberDaysMulti):
    print(f'Day {day+1}  {startOrganism:.2f}')
    startOrganism *= percDailyInc
```

Sample Output:

```
Day 1  2.00
Day 2  2.60
Day 3  3.38
Day 4  4.39
Day 5  5.71
Day 6  7.43
Day 7  9.65
Day 8  12.55
Day 9  16.31
Day 10  21.21
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of computation can be handled mathematically, using the following formula:

```
organisms = starting_organisms * ((1.0 + growth_rate) ^ days)
```

Where the `growth_rate` is the percent increase per unit of time, in your case days. Then it becomes a matter of simply printing out the value for each day.

```
starting_organisms = int(input("Starting number of organisms:"))
growth_rate = float(input("Average daily increase in percent): "))  #  0.3 = 30%
period = int(input("Number of days to grow:"))

growth = [(starting_organisms * ((1.0 + growth_rate) ** day) for day in range(period)]

# The list 'growth' has all our values, now we just print them out:
for day, population in enumerate(growth):
    print(f"Day {day} {population}")
```

(This uses a zero-index for the days. That is, 'day 0' will be your starting number. Indexing this way saves you off-by-one errors, but you can change the print statement to be `{day + 1}` to hide this data structuring from the user.)

There is an alternative method where you *carry state* in each loop, calculating the next day as you iterate. However, I'd recommend separating the concern of calculation and display - that instinct will serve you well going forward.

The `growth = [... for day in range(period)]` is a list comprehension, which works much like a one-line for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
startOrganism = 0
startOrganism = int(input("Starting number of organisms:"))

dailyInc = 0
dailyInc = float(input("Average daily increase (percent): "))

dayApproximate = 0

numberDaysMulti = 0
numberDaysMulti = int(input("Number of days to multiply: "))

for x in range(numberDaysMulti):

  startOrganism = dailyInc * startOrganism + startOrganism

  print(startOrganism)
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone for their help, here is the answer that worked for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).